# Node.js dividing server file into seperate files

Tags: node.js, split

I am learning for node.js and i came across this way to split my server file into different files so its better maintainable.

The problem is, i have looked at all these old ways to split the files into several files.
e.g.: [How to split monolithic node.js javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095528/how-to-split-monolithic-node-js-javascript)

[Divide Node App in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334051/divide-node-app-in-different-files)

[How to split a single Node.js file into separate modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000898/how-to-split-a-single-node-js-file-into-separate-modules)

[How to split Node.js files in several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946972/how-to-split-node-js-files-in-several-files)

but all these methods do not work anymore, they are outdated. and now i am trying to find a way that we can split files now. Which isnt here.. nor its in google. I am looking for it for over an hour now and i cannot find the right way to do this..

Comment: while Express.js is not the same as Node.js, they provide [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) showing how they do it which you might find helpful. Also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes).

Answer (score 4):

Those links definitely work. Here is an example

greeter.js

```
module.exports = {
    hello: function(name) {
        console.log("Hello, " + name);
    },
    bye: function(name) {
        console.log("Goodbye, " + name);
    }
};
```

index.js

```
var greeter = require('greeter');

greeter.hello("Foo");
greeter.bye("Bar");
```

[Here is the Node.js documentation for it.](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. The solution was as followed:

Files:

```
server.js (root dir)
routes.js (root dir/routes/routes.js)
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var routes = require('./routes/routes');

app.listen(3001);
routes(app);
console.log('Started listening on port : 3001');
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.end('test');
        console.log('Received GET request.');
    });
};
```

Comment: You may look at express middleware instead (rather than 'routes(routes)')

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use the (require) tag to include your documents in node.js

```
require('/home/user/module.js');
```

just put them on the right places

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file, e.g. `server.js` like this:

```
function a() {
  console.log('This is a()');
}

function b() {
  a();
}

b();
```

Then you can split it like this:

`server.js`:

```
const b = require('./b');

b();
```

`b.js`:

```
const a = require('./a');

function b() {
  a();
}

module.exports = b;
```

`a.js`

```
function a() {
  console.log('This is a()');
}

module.exports = a;
```

See the docs for more info:

- https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

See also this answer does show how to do what you want for more complicated cases than I showed here:

- [npm package.json main and project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743643/npm-package-json-main-and-project-structure/39743889#39743889)

See also those answer for some interesting details:

- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)
- [How can I export a class in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515954/how-can-i-export-a-class-in-node/40516570#40516570)